# How do I send a mp3 file back to the client side using firebase api

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-text-to-speech

How do I send an mp3 file back to the client-side using firebase API? I am using nodejs and firebase API with google text to speech(MP3 format).

When I send the audio back to my client side, its an array of number? and i cant play it using this new audio().

Client Javascript Vue

```
playSound(sound) {
    var audio = new Audio(sound);
    audio.play();
    console.log("play sound")
}
```

Server Firebase nodejs

```
exports.speak = Functions.https.onCall( asyncMiddleware( async (input, context) => {
    // Creates a client
    const client = new GTextToSpeech.TextToSpeechClient();

    // The text to synthesize
    const text = 'Hello, world!';

    // Construct the request
    const request = {
        input: {text: text},
        // Select the language and SSML Voice Gender (optional)
        voice: {languageCode: 'en-US', ssmlGender: 'NEUTRAL'},
        // Select the type of audio encoding
        audioConfig: {audioEncoding: 'MP3'},
    };

    // Performs the Text-to-Speech request
    const [response] = await client.synthesizeSpeech(request);



    return await { status: 200, message: "Successful", audio: response.audioContent }
}))
```

Comment: At a glance, you forgot to write the binary audio content to a file. `const writeFile = util.promisify(fs.writeFile);
  await writeFile('output.mp3', response.audioContent, 'binary');`. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement), the `Audio()` constructor expects a URL to the audio file. What you are passing is the binary audio content. What you could do is save it locally, as indicated above, and send it back to the client with [response.sendFile](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile)

Comment: am I able to return the mp3 files to the client without writing the files on my server then send to the client?

Comment: What is the best way to do this? I just want to do a text to speech app and play the speech(mp3) on my client.

Comment: I'm sure there's a better way, but you can have the file downloaded in the client-side like such: `var vLink = document.createElement('a');
              vBlob = new Blob([JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.body))], {type: "octet/stream"});
              vName = 'harFile.json';
              vUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(vBlob);
              vLink.setAttribute('href', vUrl);
              vLink.setAttribute('download', vName );
              vLink.click();`

Comment: This method creates a `<a>` element and simulates a click, downloading the audio content that had been sent as a response into a `.mp3` file. The issue with this method is the same as its benefit. It downloads it in the client's filesystem, this could work if you intend the client to also have the `.mp3` file but if all you want is play the speech, then this could pose an issue.

Comment: Another option, is to have it uploaded to [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/) and use its Link URL as an argument for `new Audio()`. You can then delete the uploaded objects after a certain amount of time.

Comment: To be frank, writing in the local file system shouldn't be a problem as you can delete them after a certain amount of time (the time it takes for the request to be sent  back to the browser). Do note that only the `/tmp` directory is writeable. See the [GCP docs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#file_system) for more information regarding the Cloud Functions File system.